# Visual Studio 2013 Change Authentication on Existing Project

Tags: asp.net, .net, authentication, visual-studio-2013

If I have an existing project in Visual Studio 2013, how do I change the authentication?  During a new project setup, there is a "Change Authentication" button, but I cannot find the equivalent for an existing project.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2013, I would re-run the Identity and Access Tool, available from right-clicking on the project.

Comment: Did you mean VS 2012? Right-clicking in VS 2013 shows nothing!

Comment: @nzpcmad, yes, argh!  VS2012 has the IATool.  VS2013 has nothing.  :-(

Comment: Vote for feature here: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4855136-in-vs-2013-allow-ability-to-run-the-change-authe

Comment: Hi guys I couldnt find the view in this link? Anyone can find it ?

http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio#orgauthonprem

Answer (score 9):

This can be done from project properties. I'm posting a link to the [article which explains how to do this.](http://www.get301.com/blog/2014/3/8/change-authentication-method-for-your-web-project-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Look at the section header in the Properties window, it's *Development Server*.  The question is about the project's authentication, not the server's.

Answer (score 0):

Until someone comes up with a better answer:

**Edit your web.config and FederationMetadata.xml manually.**

Answer (score 0):

If your project is ASP.NET MVC and is using the new template in 2013 it should be running on OWIN so there is a partial class Startup look inside and in case you have it there is a file
Startup.Auth.cs that is partial of Startup there I have this

```
public partial class Startup
{
    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
           LoginPath = new PathString("/Authentication/Login")
        });

        // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
        //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
        //    clientId: "",
        //    clientSecret: "");

        //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
        //   consumerKey: "",
        //   consumerSecret: "");

        //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
        //   appId: "",
        //   appSecret: "");

        //app.UseGoogleAuthentication();

    }
}
```

There, is your authentication configuration

Comment: This assumes one has installed "Open Web Interface for .NET" (Owin) via Package Manager Console:

Install-Package Owin